# React : props are undefined but when i console.log(props), it works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have an arrow function that returns this:

```
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      <Post />
      {dataApi.map((post) => {
        return <Post post={post} key={uuidv4()} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In my Post component, I try to import the author, the date and the text passed in props, but it tells me that this data is undefined. However, when I console.log (post), my data appears ... here is the code :

```
const Post = ({post}) => {
  //const {author, date_creation, message} = post
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post__author_group">
        <Avatar className={"post__avatar"} />
        <div className="post__author_and_date">
          <Author className="post__author" author={'author'} />
          <Date className="post__date" date={'date_creation'} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Text message={'message'} />
      {/* <Media /> */}
      <Interactions />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If i console.log(post), i can see my 5 objects, but if I uncomment "//const {author, date_creation, message} = post" and replace author = {'author "} with author = {author} (which is a prop), it puts me" TypeError: Cannot destructure property' author 'of' post 'as it is undefined ."

I don't know if it's related but when I console.log (post), in my console before I have my objects, I have two "undefined" but I don't know where it came from. My console :

```
Post.js: 12 undefined
Post.js: 12 undefined
Post.js: 12 {id: 1, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2020-11-11T10: 11: 11.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
Post.js: 12 {id: 2, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2020-11-11T10: 11: 11.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
Post.js: 12 {id: 3, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2017-06-29T15: 54: 04.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
Post.js: 12 {id: 4, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2021-09-03T13: 50: 33.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
Post.js: 12 {id: 5, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2021-09-03T13: 50: 49.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because your data is not loaded when your component is first time loaded. Try this:

```
const Post = ({post}) => {
if(post){
 const {author, date_creation, message} = post // You can destructure here 
 return (
    // ....
  );
}
else return null;
};
```

OR

Load the above component if you received all your data

```
 return (
    <div className="posts">
      <Post />
      {dataApi && dataApi.length > 0 && dataApi.map((post) => {
        return <Post post={post} key={uuidv4()} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: It works ! thank you so much for the quick and efficient response !!!!